# Website slowed down all of a sudden?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

My site [example page](http://eywow.com/a/test.php) is very slow, this is the server status page of [apache](http://eywow.com/server-status) My guess is that the iptables are slowing it down, as there is no reason from the hardware side, there are enough free resources. I have 8 GB Ram and 4 CPUs.